# How to trim part of the column names (TCGA patient ID) in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data.table

I have a dataset with TCGA patient ID as the column names. What I want to do is that removing the latter part of the names, but retaining forepart of them. My data:

```
GeneID        | TCGA-3L-AA1B-01A-11R-A37K-07   | TCGA-4N-A93T-01A-11R-A37K-07 | TCGA-4T-AA8H-01A-11R-A41B-07
------------- | -------------------------------| -----------------------------|------------------------------
100130426     | 0.5174                         | 0.0000                       |0.0000
100133144     | 18.0851                        | 4.4315                       |9.8995
```

The column names I want to retain as follows:

```
GeneID        | TCGA-3L-AA1B-01A               | TCGA-4N-A93T-01A             | TCGA-4T-AA8H-01A
------------- | -------------------------------| -----------------------------|------------------------------
100130426     | 0.5174                         | 0.0000                       |0.0000
100133144     | 18.0851                        | 4.4315                       |9.8995
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `strsplit`

```
names(df)[-1] <- sapply(strsplit(names(df)[-1], "-"), function(x) paste0(x[1:4], collapse = "-"))
df
#     GeneID TCGA-3L-AA1B-01A TCGA-4N-A93T-01A TCGA-4T-AA8H-01A
#1 100130426           0.5174           0.0000           0.0000
#2 100133144          18.0851           4.4315           9.8995
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "100130426      0.5174                          0.0000                       0.0000
100133144      18.0851                         4.4315                       9.8995", header = F)
names(df) <- c("GeneID", "TCGA-3L-AA1B-01A-11R-A37K-07", "TCGA-4N-A93T-01A-11R-A37K-07", "TCGA-4T-AA8H-01A-11R-A41B-07")
```

Comment: You're very welcome @JasonXie; please consider closing this question by setting the green check mark next to one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
names(df) <- substr(names(df),1,16)
```

or

```
names(df) <- sub("-[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+$","",names(df))
```